# Запятая перед "и" во вставной конструкции

Tags: пунктуация

> ...Начала учить латынь по старому, завалявшемуся на чердаке учебнику,
>   а также включила в свой круг чтения периодическую печать – «Наука и
>   жизнь», «Химия и жизнь» (тут я, к сожалению, понимала только
>   научно-фантастические рассказы и, нужно отметить, что у главного
>   редактора этого издания был отменный литературный вкус).

Права ли я, предлагая:

*...тут я, к сожалению, понимала только научно-фантастические рассказы, и нужно отметить, что у главного редактора этого издания был отменный литературный вкус.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Запятая нужна, внутри вставки сочинительная связь, союз И.**

...тут я, к сожалению, понимала только научно-фантастические рассказы, и нужно отметить, что у главного редактора этого издания был отменный литературный вкус.

2) При отсутствии "нужно отметить" возможно **другое понимание конструкции:**

..тут я, к сожалению, **понимала** (что?) только научно-фантастические рассказы и что у главного редактора этого издания был отменный литературный вкус. Здесь однородные отношения между дополнением "рассказы" и придаточным предложением с союзом ЧТО, одиночный союз И, запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 2):

Смысл в том, что (1) читала научно-фантастические рассказы и **при этом**  обнаружила, что (2) у главного редактора этого издания был отменный литературный вкус.

Союз "и" должен связывает (1) и (2), "нужно отметить" - служить вставкой.

**тут я, к сожалению, понимала только научно-фантастические рассказы, и, нужно отметить, у главного редактора этого издания был отменный литературный вкус**

или

**тут я, к сожалению, понимала только научно-фантастические рассказы, и - нужно отметить - у главного редактора этого издания был отменный литературный вкус**

А если написать "нужно отметить, что ...", то "нужно отметить" перестает быть вставкой и становится сказуемым во втором предложении, его роль несоразмерно возрастает и смысл фразы меняется: во-первых, читала, во-вторых, нужно отметить.